# C++ iterator to const_iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, const-iterator

How do I acquire a `const_iterator` (of some container class) from an `iterator` (of that container class) in C++? What about a `const_iterator` from an `insert_iterator`? The resulting `iterator` should point at the same spot as the original does.

Comment: @Pubby8: Don't even need a cast!

Comment: Huh, I must have messed up. I thought I got a compiler error when I tried to implicitly convert them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Containers are required to provide `iterator` as a type convertible to `const_iterator`, so you can convert implicitly:

```
Container::iterator it = /* blah */;
Container::const_iterator cit = it;
```

`std::insert_iterator`s are output iterators. This gives no way to convert them to a regular `Container::iterator` which must be a forward iterator.

Another kind of insert iterator *may* allow such a thing, but those obtained from the standard functions don't.

I guess you can write your own wrapper around `std::insert_iterator` that exposes the protected member `iter`, though:

```
template <typename Container>
class exposing_insert_iterator : public std::insert_iterator<Container> {
public:
    exposing_insert_iterator(std::insert_iterator<Container> it)
    : std::insert_iterator<Container>(it) {}
    typename Container::iterator get_iterator() const {
        return std::insert_iterator<Container>::iter;
    }
};

// ...
std::insert_iterator<Container> ins_it;
exposing_insert_iterator<Container> exp_it = ins_it;
Container::iterator it = exp_it.get_iterator();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert them. Example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = it;
```

But I guess that is not the answer you are seeking. Show me code. :-)