# Is There a make_const_iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, stl-algorithm, const-iterator

There are times when I'll want to use the iterator returned by a function from the algorithm library. The problem I'm facing occurs when I go between a modifying function and a non-modifying function. Cause in the non-modifying function I want to use a `const_iterator`. As a toy example:

```
vector<int> v = { 1, 8, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 5 };
auto it = partition(begin(v), end(v), bind(greater<int>(), placeholders::_1, 3));

cout << (find(cbegin(v), it, 13) != cend(v)) << endl;
```

When I try to compile this code I get the error:

> no matching function for call to `find(std::vector<int>::const_iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&, int)`

The problem I'm running into is the only conversion process I can find is potentially expensive: `auto cit = next(cbegin(v), distance(begin(v), it))`

Is there a way I can make this work? Or am I stuck converting or just using non-`const_iterator`s?

Comment: Just a preemptive comment, I know that I could just use `find` directly on `v`. I'm not looking for a better way to write my toy example; I'm looking for a solution to the problem it illustrates.

Comment: Have you tried just constructing a const_iterator from the normal one?

Comment: Are we to assume that the type of the original container is unknown? If not, `decltype(v)::const_iterator(it)` does the trick. Using `cvegin(v)` in your proposed solution seems to imply you have access to `v`, and not only the iterator.

Comment: All STL container `iterator` are convertible to its `const_iterator`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759246/c-iterator-to-const-iterator)

Comment: Maybe using `std::list` would be better for the toy example, otherwise assertions such as `distance` being expensive don't hold.

Comment: the other way around (const_iterator to iterator) would be problematic...

Comment: @mike Yeah, when I realized you could cast that was my next question. I'll ask tomorrow or you can now, but if you do please link so i can find it.

Comment: @JonathanMee something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765148/how-to-remove-constness-of-const-iterator

Comment: @clcto Great link! Thanks for protecting me from duping. [James McNellis's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10669041/2642059) is particularly headsploding. It doesn't makes sense that it hasn't been accepted since `const_iterator`s are only available for containers (and arrays for which pointer arithmetic is inexpensive.)

Comment: nice link - Scott Meyers have not included it in item 13 of his Effective Modern C++. He states that in c++11 conversion of const_iterator to iterator is UB. But he mentions that there are ways to accomplish that but they are not worth including in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much less expensive to simply cast the mutable iterator to a constant iterator:

```
cout << (find(cbegin(v), vector<int>::const_iterator{it}, 13)
      != cend(v)) << endl;
```

A mutable iterator should always be castable into a constant iterator.

EDIT: I found the part of the standard that guarantees that an iterator is convertible to a constant iterator.

Table 96  in section 23.2 "Container requirements" specifies that the expression `X::iterator` results in:

> any iterator category
>   that meets the
>   forward iterator
>   requirements.
>   convertible to
>   X::const_iterator.

Comment: Is there a guaranteed such conversion?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7759474/1294207

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: That's fantastic, thanks. I sort of trust the Good Robot. But a standard ref. would have clinched the matter.

Comment: "Note: iterator and const_-iterator have identical semantics in this case, and iterator is convertible to const_iterator." - I found this wording explicitly copy-pasted between 23.2.4, associative containers, and 23.2.5 unordered associative containers. Curiously it is missing from 23.3, sequence containers, which seems to be an oversight, unless it is worded slightly differently.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik interesting. Since all these answers point out that this is a legal cast (which I didn't know) I'd really like if one of the answers could differentiate by demonstrating this is defined per the standard.

Comment: @JonathanMee -- found the cite from the standard, that seems to apply to all iterator types.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the template argument:

```
find<decltype(cbegin(v))>(cbegin(v), it, 13) != cend(v)
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/ZfQTNc)

Comment: I see the error is actually because I'm cause ambiguity in the template deduction of `find`. So this is the same as the other examples, forcing a cast. Is there a statement anywhere that such a cast is legal, and not just implementation defined?

Answer (score 1):

There are three approaches.

The first one is to write

```
cout << (find( begin(v), it, 13) != cend(v)) << endl;
               ^^^^^
```

The second one is to write

```
cout << (find(cbegin(v), static_cast<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>( it )
, 13) != cend(v)) << endl;
```

Or shorter

```
cout << (find(cbegin(v), static_cast<decltype( v.cbegin())>( it )
, 13) != cend(v)) << endl;
```

And the third one is to write

```
cout << (find<std::vector<int>>::const_iterator>( cbegin(v), it, 13) != cend(v)) << endl;
```

or shorter

```
cout << (find<decltype( v.cbegin())>( cbegin(v), it, 13) != cend(v)) << endl;
```

Comment: Yeah i mention in the question that **1** is undesirable. The other 2 options are both effectively casting to a `const_iterator` (which I didn't know you could do.) Is there anything in the standard that explicitly allows this?

Comment: @JonathanMee See in the Table 96 — Container requirements  the row about iterators.